# Running a SavedModel in TensorFlow 2 with inputs of a specific type

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run an object detection model I have prepared in SavedModel format in TensorFlow 2.

The model takes inputs in the format of a byte-encoded JPEG, PNG, or GIF as **encoded_image_string_tensor:0** and outputs the typical **detection_scores:0**, **detection_boxes:0**, etc.

In TensorFlow 1.15, I can do the following operations:

```py
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], path_to_model)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret, encoded = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
    inferred = sess.run(["detection_scores:0", "detection_boxes:0"], feed_dict={
        "encoded_image_string_tensor:0": [encoded.tobytes(),]
    })
    # Use the outputs from here
```

I've been trying to convert this code to use TensorFlow 2's new APIs instead of the compatibility libraries, but I keep running into roadblocks. Here's the code I have been trying to use with TensorFlow 2:

```py
loaded = tf.saved_model.load(path_to_model)
infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
# `encoded` is the same as the prior example,
# and TF2 is always requesting "image_bytes" and "key" as inputs
prediction = infer(image_bytes=encoded.tobytes(), key="")
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1551, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1591, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1684, in _call_flat
    "Tensor." % (self._func_graph.name, i, str(arg)))
ValueError: All inputs to `ConcreteFunction`s must be Tensors; on invocation of pruned, the 0-th input (b'...') was not a Tensor.
"""
```

Is there a functional TensorFlow 2.x equivalent to the TensorFlow 1.x code that doesn't use the compatibility libraries, or am I approaching this the completely wrong way?

I've been referencing the SavedModel documentation from TensorFlow, available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem seems to be:

```
All inputs to `ConcreteFunction`s must be Tensors...
```

So instead of passing in `encoded.tobytes()` maybe try passing in `tf.convert_to_tensor(encoded.tobytes())`.

Alternatively, check out the documentation for [tf.io.encode_jpeg](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/encode_jpeg), which seems to provide image-specific tensor convertion.